# @RefreshScope not working on Spring Boot 3.0.6

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-config-server

I'm having a problem when I trying refreshing scope of my application to get properties in a microservice using Spring Boot 3.0.6

Schenary

- I have a config-server running connected with my Github
- My Github contains a file with properties from my user-service-api
- When I call config server to get user-service-api properties (http://localhost:8888/user-service-api/dev) I have this response

```
{
    "name": "user-service-api",
    "profiles": [
        "dev"
    ],
    "label": null,
    "version": "90baae4177b982a490fe7400f8659952bceaddfa",
    "state": null,
    "propertySources": [
        {
            "name": "https://github.com/ValdirCezar/formacao-backend-expert-configs/user-service-api-dev.yml",
            "source": {
                "spring.application.name": "user-service-api",
                "spring.data.mongodb.auto-index-creation": true,
                "springdoc.openapi.title": "User Service API TEST",
                "springdoc.openapi.version": "1.0.0",
                "server.port": "${SERVER_PORT:8080}"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

When I change properties in my github

```
spring:
  application:
    name: 'user-service-api'
  data:
springdoc:
  openapi:
    title: 'User Service API'
    version: '1.0.0'
server:
  port: ${SERVER_PORT:8080}
```

The config server response is updated

---

In my user-service-api

**application.yml**

```
spring:
  application:
    name: 'user-service-api'
  cloud:
    config:
      uri: ${CONFIG_SERVER_URI:http://localhost:8888}
```

**bootstrap.yml**

```
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: '*'
```

I added the @RefresScope on my OpenAPI Config class

```
@RefreshScope
@Configuration
public class OpenAPIConfig {

    @Bean
    public OpenAPI customOpenAPI(
            @Value("${springdoc.openapi.title}") final String title,
            @Value("${springdoc.openapi.description}") final String description,
            @Value("${springdoc.openapi.version}") final String version
    ) {
        return new OpenAPI()
                .info(new Info()
                        .title(title)
                        .description(description)
                        .version(version)
                );
    }
}
```

**dependencies**

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.0.8'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.0'
}
```

```
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap'

    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
```

When I reload the application, this configs update, but when I call http://localhost:8888/actuator/refresh to refresh scope not working

With spring boot 2.0.6 works but not with 3.0.6